# Combining or appending to pyarrow.dataset.expressions

Tags: python, expression, pyarrow

I am trying to filter pyarrow data with pyarrow.dataset. I want to add a dynamic way to add to the expressions.

```
from pyarrow import parquet as pq
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import datetime

exp1 = ds.field("IntCol") == 1
exp2 = ds.field("StrCol") == 'A'
exp3 = ds.field("DateCol") == datetime.date.today()

filters = (exp1 & exp2 & exp3)
print(filters)

#To be used in reading parquet tables
df = pq.read_table('sample.parquet', filters=filters)
```

How can do this without writing "&" there since I may have N number of exps? I have been looking at different ways to collect expressions like np.logical_and.accumulate(). It gets me partially there, but I still need to convert the array into a single expression.

```
np.logical_and.accumulate([exp1, exp2, exp3])

out: array([<pyarrow.dataset.Expression (IntCol == 1)>,
       <pyarrow.dataset.Expression (StrCol == "A")>,
       <pyarrow.dataset.Expression (DateCol == 2021-06-09)>], dtype=object)
```

going down numpy route may not be the best answer. Does anyone have suggestion whether this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `operator.and_` to have the functional equivalent of the `&` operator. And then with `functools.reduce` it can be recursively applied on a list of expressions.

Using your three example expressions:

```py
import operator
import functools

>>> functools.reduce(operator.and_, [exp1, exp2, exp3])
<pyarrow.dataset.Expression (((IntCol == 1) and (StrCol == "A")) and (DateCol == 2021-06-10))>
```